Replacement for Expo Face Detector?
I have a react native expo app that relied heavily on expo face detector. I have been notified by the google play store that apps need to target a new minimum API version and In my case Is the expo version. I have upgraded the app to expo 51 to Find that they no longer support expo face detection in expo 51. They recommended using react-native-vision camera as a replacement, which out of the box, does not support face detection. I have tried several different face detection frame processors that are made for react-native-vision camera and although they install properly into my code, when I go to build a binary of the app with EAS, they always fail to build at run gradelw.  Has anyone had any luck implementing face detection of any kind into a managed expo 51 app?
My binaries always build properly with eas with the following package.json:
I have also added ['react-native-worklets-core/plugin'] to babel.config.js as they require.
"dependencies": {
        "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.23.1",
        "@react-native-community/slider": "4.5.2",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.1",
        "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.7",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5",
        "axios": "^1.2.2",
        "babel-preset-fbjs": "^3.4.0",
        "expo": "~51.0.19",
        "expo-camera": "~15.0.13",
        "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.20",
        "expo-screen-orientation": "~7.0.5",
        "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.2",
        "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
        "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
        "expo-updates": "~0.25.18",
        "i18next": "^23.3.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-i18next": "^13.0.2",
        "react-native": "0.74.3",
        "react-native-awesome-alerts": "^2.0.0",
        "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
        "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
        "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
        "react-native-vision-camera": "^4.4.2",
        "react-native-worklets-core": "^1.3.3",
        "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
        "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
        "zustand": "^4.3.2"
    },

But as soon as i try to add a frame processor for the face detection, my builds always fail with
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

Again, this is a Managed expo app.

@chiragprajapati I did not make any progress on this Issue and also reverted back to expo 50. The good news is that the warning provided by the Google play store is gone. There must have been some mistake or something Expo fixed behind the scenes. not sure
